# How can I add names to a cell and write better formulas?

Tags: excel, variables

I've seen formulas using variables instead of addresses, and they're so much more intuitive. How do I do it?

I looked through the menus, but nothing stands out, and since I don't know what the variables are called, I'm stuck.

Comment: Check Named ranges" at Formula -> Define name

Answer (score 1):

The "variables" are called Names.
Whenever you select a cell or range of cells the address of your selection will be displayed to the far left of your formula-field.
If you want to name a range, simply overwrite that address with any valid name.

- Yes, it's that simple.

If you need to change or delete a name the button you didn't know you were looking for is called Names, and by default it's located in the Formula-ribbon.

Now you can write functions like =sum(prices)*vat

Glad I asked. I love this for team efforts and for debugging complex formulas.

Comment: Consider add ing that you can define functions as names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're referring to formulas directly, but there's a "Fx" symbol which allows you to type in an input of what you're looking for with the variables of the function, instead of having to type out the function entirely by hand.

Photo of "Fx" symbol for typing in functions and variables:
[image: Photo of "Fx" symbol for typing in functions and variables]

Comment: Thanks Dylan. I was actually just sharing my best beginners tip, trying to get enough reputation for me to participate in a separate issue I'm having. 
The tip is to name your ranges and improve readability of functions.  Since you're here I'm guessing you write functions. Since you didn't get my question I expect your about to have your world blown like i did two years ago. Please, have a second look at my proposed solution.